# BouncyCastle - (AES/GCM/NoPadding) and SecretKeySpec in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, bouncycastle

I'm having trouble converting this BouncyCastle java code to a c# version.

specifically this section I'm having trouble converting:

```
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");

         cipher.init(
                 Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
                 new SecretKeySpec(keyMaterial, "AES"), //C# version??
                 new IvParameterSpec(iv)
         );
```

Not sure what the c# version of new SecretKeySpec(keyMaterial, "AES"), would be.
The full java source is here: [Java BouncyCastle source code trying to convert link](http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/com/heartlandpaymentsystems/secure-submit/v2.0.2&path=/Source%20Packages/main.java.com.hps.integrator.applepay.ecv1/DecryptService.java)

Thanks for any help if anyone has been down this road already.

{Update:}

```
    public byte[] kdf(byte[] z, byte[] otherInfo) 
    {
        //Java BC
        //Digest digest = new SHA256Digest();
        //byte[] result = new byte[digest.getDigestSize()];
        //digest.update((byte)(1 >> 24));
        //digest.update((byte)(1 >> 16));
        //digest.update((byte)(1 >> 8));
        //digest.update((byte)1);
        //digest.update(z, 0, z.length);
        //digest.update(otherInfo, 0, otherInfo.length);
        //digest.doFinal(result, 0);
        //return result;

        // C# BC
        IDigest digest = new Sha256Digest();
        byte[] result = new byte[digest.GetDigestSize()];
        digest.Update((byte)(1 >> 24));
        digest.Update((byte)(1 >> 16));
        digest.Update((byte)(1 >> 8));
        digest.Update((byte)1);
        digest.BlockUpdate(z, 0, z.Length);
        digest.BlockUpdate(otherInfo, 0, otherInfo.Length);
        digest.DoFinal(result, 0);

        return result;
    }
```

And the Gcm AES C# BC version would be:

```
        byte[] aesKeyData = kdf(sharedSecret, other);
        var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesFastEngine());
        KeyParameter keyParameter = ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", aesKeyData);
        ICipherParameters cipherParameters = new ParametersWithIV(keyParameter, IV);
        cipher.Init(false, cipherParameters);

        byte[] output = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(ciphertext.Length)];
        int len = cipher.ProcessBytes(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.Length, output, 0);
        try
        {
            cipher.DoFinal(output, len);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Maybe others will find this info helpful.

Comment: It would be your AES key (bytes).

Comment: Thanks Artjom, I would need a little more info. My question is more a BC c#/java syntax question.  specifically what the c# IDigest with keyMaterial equivalent would look like.

Comment: Updated the question with more info and progress.  I'm not sure about the NoPadding in the Java version, I'm getting [mac check in GCM failed] now but I'm not sure if I have an input data issue somewhere.

Comment: (1) Have you checked that `aesKeyData` (C#) and `keyMaterial` (Java) contains the same value? Have you checked that the IV is the same? Have you checked that the ciphertext has the same length? (2) NoPadding for GCM is correct.

Comment: Thanks Artjom, my comment about NoPadding was in regards to [I don't see the C# equivalent NoPadding setting], not questioning if NoPadding is correct.  I don't have a java code environment for an Apples to Apples testing, but looks like I may have to go down that road to see where my issue is, but I will try other .net test before I do, and I hope others may have input to where the issue may be.

Comment: Turns out I have to use the var cipher = WrapperUtilities.GetWrapper("AES/GCM/NoPadding") so forget that code in the question notes...

Comment: If it works, then you can provide an answer to your question. I'm still not sure why that would work.